# How to overwrite the initial State in Redux

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-thunk

I am writing an application using the backend and I need to make when I open the application. A request was made to the server from which come right condition. Which should rewrite the entire application state.

But now, I can only assign it to the facility "loading/data" and the need only to completely overwrite the Root Redux state.

response from server: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UClx8.jpg

redux state: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJclL.jpg

> actions/loading.js

```
export function fetchTodos(path) {
  return function (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: FETCH_TODOS_REQUEST,
    });
    return axios
      .get(`http://localhost:3000${path}`)
      .then((response) => {
        const { data } = response;
        console.log('data', data);
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS,
          data,
        });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const { data } = error.response;
        console.log('data', data);
        dispatch({
          type: FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE,
          error: data,
        });
      });
  };
```

> reducers/index.js

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  loading,
  Header,
  Main,
  routing: routerReducer,
});

export default rootReducer;
```

> reducers/loading.js

```
export function loading(state = initialState.loading, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case FETCH_TODOS_REQUEST:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: true,
      });
    case FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        data: action.data.data,
      });
    case FETCH_TODOS_FAILURE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        isFetching: false,
        error: action.error,
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

> store/index.js

```
function configureStoreProd(initialState) {
  return createStore(rootReducer, initialState);
}

function configureStoreDev(initialState) {
  const middlewares = [
    thunk,
  ];
  const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
  const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(...middlewares),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hook into the `FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS` action in your `Header` and `Main` reducers.

When you combine reducers then each reducer's `state` data contains only that reducer's segment.

For example, your `loading` reducer will have access to the `state.loading` segment of your store. To update your store's `Main` segment, you could do something like:

```
// reducers/Main.js

export default (state = initialState.Main, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case FETCH_TODOS_SUCCESS:
            const newMainData = action.data.data.main;

            return Object.assign({}, state, newMainData);
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

As a side note, you should only user uppercase variables for *instantiated-type* variables (e.g. class-like objects).

Also, don't forget to update your `loading` reducer to only pull the loading data from your server response.